# How to remove the json. prefix on my elasticsearch field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I use ELK to get some info on my rabbitmq stuff.
Here my conf logstash side

```
json {
    source => "message"
}
```

But in kibana I have to prefix all my fields with json.xxx:
json.sender, json.sender.raw,json.programld, json.programId.raw ...

How can I **not** have this json.-prefix in my field names, so that I only have to have: sender, programId, etc.?

Best regards and thanks for your help !

Bonus question : what are all these .'raw' I must use in kibana ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html):

> By default it will place the parsed JSON in the root (top level) of
>   the Logstash event, but this filter can be configured to place the
>   JSON into any arbitrary event field, using the target configuration.

So it feels like your json is wrapped in a container named "json" or you're setting the "target" in logstash without showing us.

As for ".raw", the default elasticsearch mapping will analyze the data you put in a field, so changing "/var/log/messages" into three words: [var, log, messages]" which can make it hard to search.  To keep you from having to worry about this at the beginning, logstash creates a ".raw" version of each string, which is not analyzed.

You'll eventually make your own mappings, and you can make the original field not_analyzed, so you won't need the .raw versions anymore.

Comment: Thanks Alain for your answer. You're right, my first try was with the target=>json but then I change it back to what you can see. Now I'll wait until tomorrow to see if I can get rid of all this json.xxx which are not at all what I want.